# Apple Pushnotification Feedback service

Tags: php, ios, zend-framework, notifications, apns-php

I have a problem with IOS push notification. I am using php(Zend) as a provider. I have tested the notification in below scenarios:

1) Installed app in my iPhone and sends the device token to server and it is successfully stored in database. Then i have fired a notification, and i have received notification.

2) Then i have uninstalled the app from device and fired a notification. In this scenario APNS doesn't returned any error message. Feedback service also not gave any invalid tokens (Device has other apps which has push notification enabled).

3) Installed app again then send the notification. Now, The notification is successfully sent.

So my question is, why apns not returned invalid token when app is uninstalled from the device. Why feedback service not returned any invalid tokens?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall an application, it does not get de-registered from the push server. So, this is normal behaviour. You won't get any invalid token error.

Comment: Thanks for reply Hamza Azad. But in APNS documentation, clearly mentioned.
"If you remove your app from your device or computer and then send a push notification to it, you would expect to have the device token rejected, and the invalidated device token should appear on the feedback service".
[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG2)

Comment: The next line says: "However, if this was the last push-enabled app on the device or computer, it will not show up in the feedback service. This is because deleting the last app tears down the persistent connection to the push service before the notice of the deletion can be sent. You can work around this by leaving at least one push-enabled app on the device or computer. Just install any free push-enabled app from the App Store and you should then be able to delete your app and see it appear in the feedback service." Hope this clears it up.

Comment: Thanks for reply Hamza Azad, I have already mentioned in my question that my device has other apps which has push notification enabled and The installed and removed apps both are points to production mode only